# The same tag can be in both interesting tags and ignored tags list. They should be mutually exclusive

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

I'm listing this both as a bug and a feature request since it's subjective as to which it might be.

I discovered while discussing another feature request that I can mark a tag as both Ignored *and* Interesting. This leads to question lists that look like this:

[image]

Now, perhaps this is intended behavior, but it seems counter-intuitive to me. I would argue that it would be best to make ignore / interesting mutually exclusive. If you try to add one and it's on the other list, you get the Red Popup of DOOM telling you to remove it from the other list first.

**Edit:** Well, I have my answer: it's by design. I can live with that. Just seems counter-intuitive, is all.

Comment: I tried to clarify your title, since it seemed to be misleading some.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thanks!

Comment: why is it by design?

Comment: It seems this is no longer ([meta-tag:status-bydesign]). Adding a watched tag to the list of ignored tags will remove it from the list of watched tags. I haven't tested what happens when one uses wildcards, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than red popup of doom, I'd suggest just take the tag off of the other list.  If they can't remember that they are already interested in it or ignoring it, then that is probably what they want anyway.

Comment: I'd be happy with that as well.

Although I like Red Popup of DOOM. Just kinda rolls off the tongue.

Comment: I can see how it would be useful when using selector tags, like foo-* on your ignore, but you can still add an interesting tag like foo-foo, while still ignoring foo-bar, foo-example, etc.

Comment: Excellent point, Ian

Comment: @Ian i didn't realize you could use a wildcard in an interesting/ignored tag

Answer (score 1):

It's like a tag you want to turn away from, but you just can't.  You hate it, but you find it fascinating. :)  Also, that's the only way to force a tag into the 3rd color.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the current behavior is "buggy". The fact is that if you know a question can have a broad audience, the more tags you put, the more probable is that it gets restricted in visibility. I just posted an answer involving linux, windows and osx, because I'd like to make a comparison. I ended up tagging without the obvious tags, because it's highly probable that if one is interested in one, he is also not interested in the others, meaning that more tags would result in less visibility. This goes against the purpose of tagging in the first place.

Comment: i can't speak for everyone, but i am more likely to look at a post that is tagged with both an interesting and uniteresting tag than i am to look at one that is not tagged with either.  also, tags are heavily weighted for search results.  that means tagging appropriately will allow more people to find your question from a search, and most people upvote a question they find via search that helps them out.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is an end user error that is simple enough for the end user to fix, that it is not worth the effort (design, implementation and maintenance) to make impossible.