# Exclusion/inclusion strategy with ignored/interesting tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Hello,

I noted something rather annoying (or maybe it's from specs, but I find it deceiving).
I made a question having the tags linux, windows and osx (because the question specifically asks for all three of them).

In my tag filtering, I am interested in linux but I exclude windows. The end result was that my question was hidden (transparent, and I guess completely hidden if configured it as such), but at the same time highlighted in orange.

In my opinion, this is a bug. If something contains a tag I am interested to, it should overrule the fact that it also contains tags I am not interested to. If I want to address a broad audience (which would be the reason why tag it linux, windows, osx) putting all the three tags is a guarantee for having the question receiving only those readers who don't have any of them in their exclude list (not many, I guess)

Comment: Possible dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/ - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/

Comment: agreed on the dupe. it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug, most likely by-design. Some may want to filter where ignored tags are applied regardless. An example would be if I enjoy PHP by have absolutely no interest in MySQL. I don't want to see any MySQL tags even if they apply to PHP.

There's clearly two sides to this camp, and it adds quite a bit of complexity to accommodate both, and would add confusion to the UI. I don't know which behaviour is the *more* desired one by the public, though.

Comment: @Ian Elliot So isn't that basic principle that if you don't know which behaviour is more desired you should live it to the user to decide? It makes sense for me.