# Should there be an "uninteresting" tag filter

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags, filtering

Basically I ask this because of the current behavior of the ignored and interesting filter list.  If a post has a tag in both of these lists, it is ignored.  It appears from [an earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10979/exclusion-inclusion-strategy-with-ignored-interesting-tags) that this behavior isn't going to change, but it makes it difficult to filter questions if your interests are fairly narrow.

I would like to propose that a third filter be added, an *Uninteresting* filter.  A Post matching this filter would remain if it also has an *Interesting* tag, but otherwise be removed or greyed out.  The *Ignored* filter would continue to override either of these.

From a user's perspective, this third filter would be a weaker form of ignoring, and allow conditional ignoring of certain tags.  For example, if I was interested in SQL, but not Python per se, I can still see questions with both python and sql tags, but ignore tags with just python, for which I have no strong interest.

Answer (score 3):

You can have "ignored" tags grayed out (that was the default at some time, I think that has changed) and with that setting acts exactly as what you are proposing.

A question tagged SQL and Python would show (on SO) light orange/yellow.

http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/2976/ignoredo.jpg

I just skim the Ignored+Interesting questions and depending on the wording/tags, I decide to enter or not.

If you have to edit this, just go to your pref tab on your user page:

http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/7641/hidez.jpg

If you want to hide the ignored questions and keep the *both* questions, you could go the Greasemonkey route.

Comment: With ignored questions showing, I have 28/50 grey or light orange on the first page.  This is a lot of crap to wade through.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for showing me how to show ignored tags.  I'm not an idiot.

Comment: @ergosys: there is a difference between being idiot and inexperienced with the site. You've been a member for 15 days and you are already making feature requests. The wording on the answer made me think that you wanted the "both" behavior. Train your eyes, every one in a while an ignored question might be worth your time to learn something new.

Comment: Sorry CW, there's too much to wade through.  Ideally, I'd want to show only questions with my interesting tags (ie uninteresting=*).  I think only about 10-20% of the questions would remain then.