# What happens if a question contains ignored and favorite tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Exclusion/inclusion strategy with ignored/interesting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10979/exclusion-inclusion-strategy-with-ignored-interesting-tags)

Is there special treatment for questions that contain both favorite and ignored tags?

For example, I am interested in SQLite questions and not in iPhone questions, but the question has both since the person has an SQLite-specific question, but he develops only for iPhone, so I used this tag also. Will this question be visible in 'interested'?