# Why can a tag be marked both as interesting and ignored at the same time?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Why is it allowed to add the same tag to the interesting and ignored tags' lists?

Comment: Related: [The same tag can be in both interesting tags and ignored tags list. They should be mutually exclusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that in most cases, it is a mistake, it is small and easily correctable.

On the other hand, if someone has a variety of tags that they want to temporarily ignore, it would make sense that they can add them to the ignore list without being forced to remove them from the interesting tags.

I wouldn't call this a bug. I'd call it a feature.

Comment: Agreed, software that tries too hard to enforce ideas of what make sense to one person end up failing someone else in frustrating ways.  Wait until something is demonstrated to cause problems before deciding it needs to be corrected.  This is the attitude the dev team has taken in the past, for the most part.